# Got "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection" in my redux action with firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I got the following error and I'm looking for the solution.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.type')
```

I found a lot of questions about this problem, almost solutions are inserting `throw error` into `catch` statement.
So I tried it, but the error's not gone.

What is wrong with my code?

***Technologies***

- react-native
- redux
- react-navigation

This is my code.

- Action

```
:

export function requestSignIn(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    // change loading status
    dispatch(startedRequest());

    if (email && password) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(response => {
          if (response) {
            // save email and password in local secure storage.
            SecureStorage.setItem('email', email);
            SecureStorage.setItem('password', password);

            // save uid into store
            dispatch(requestSignInSuccess(response.user.uid));

            dispatch(NavigationService.navigate('Home', { uid: response.user.uid }));
          } else {
            dispatch(requestSignInFailure('network error'));
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // I tried inserting 'throw error' here.
          // throw error;
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('user not found'));
              break;
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('invalid email'));
              break;
            default:
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('something went wrong'));
          }
        })

    } else {
      dispatch(requestSignInFailure('error message from else statement'))
    }
  }
}

export function requestSignInSuccess(uid) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      uid: uid
    }
  }
}

export function requestSignInFailure(errorMessage) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
    payload: {
      errorMessage: errorMessage
    }
  }
}
```

- The component calls the above Action

```
:

class SignIn extends Component {

  async handleSignIn() {
    const { requestSignIn } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = this.props.auth;
    Keyboard.dismiss();

    requestSignIn(email, password);
  }
:
```

***Addition***

I removed the statement `dispatch(NavigationService.navigate('Home', { uid: response.user.uid }));`, the error won't appear.

The cause of the problem is the screen has changed while the function is running?

If it's true, how do I execute `dispatch(NavigationService.navigate('Home', { uid: response.user.uid }));` 
after `dispatch(requestSignInSuccess(response.user.uid));` finished?

Comment: SecureStorage.setItem is an async func.

Comment: @Horst I tried removing `SecureStorage.setItem('email', email)` and `SecureStorage.setItem('passowrd', password)`, but the same error message appeared.